# how to navigate between tabs using a button on react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have the following pages in my app

- Login
- Register
- Dashboard [Home, Settings, Profile]
- EditProfile

the pages "Home, Settings, Profile" are grouped within a MaterialBottomTabNavigator, in this model:

// **Dashboard**

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Scheduling: { screen: Settings },
        Profile: { screen: Profile, },

    }, { initialRouteName: 'Home' }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

// **EditProfile**

```
export default function EditProfile({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
    </View>
  );
}
```

the "EditProfile" page is not grouped in "MaterialBottomTabNavigator"

is there any way to create an "anchor" button on the "Edit profile" page that navigates to the "Dashboard" page in the Profile tab?

Obs: navigating to the "Profile" page works, however MaterialBottomTabNavigator is not rendered, as it only exists on the "Dashboard" page

sorry for my english

Comment: Hi, Welcome! Are you using react-native-navigation? If so, could you please share the whole Navigation Stack code?

Comment: Yes you can use switchNavigator refer this for more
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/animated-switch-navigator.html